# Expression resolves to an unused function, in Swift UI. can't figure out what the problem is

Tags: swift, swiftui

I kept getting the error seen in the title. I'm not sure what it really means. If I move it somewhere else it says that there is no type of function in the content view.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var Option = ["1-10","1-100","L or D","Custom"]
    @State private var Random = Int.random(in: 0...4)
    @State private var num = 0


    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section {
                    Text("Za Warudo")
                }
                .padding(150)

                Section {
                    ForEach(0 ..< Option.count) { number in
                        Button(action: {
                            self.MyButton
                        }) {
                            Text("welpo")

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        .navigationBarTitle("We Need Help")
        }
    }
    func MyButton() {
        num += 1
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To call the function as the button action, you need to use a function *call* -- include the parentheses with any parameters -- not just the function name (without the parentheses).

The convention for variable and function names in Swift is [lower camel case](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lowerCamelCase), so you should consider beginning the function name with a lowercase character.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var Option = ["1-10","1-100","L or D","Custom"]
    @State private var Random = Int.random(in: 0...4)
    @State private var num = 0


    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section {
                    Text("Za Warudo")
                }
                .padding(150)

                Section {
                    ForEach(0 ..< Option.count) { number in
                        Button(action: {
                            self.myButtonAction()
                        }) {
                            Text("welpo")

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("We Need Help")
        }
    }

    func myButtonAction() {
        num += 1
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i spent such a long time trying to figure this out.  And the solution was relatively simple LOL.

Comment: No problem. Glad it helped.